# Spring RestTemplate, how to handle chucked transfer encoding

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I'm making a get request to a vendor's Saas API. The response I get is xml (will not honor application/json request). The header I'm getting back states that it chucked:

```
 Content-Type=[text/xml;charset=UTF-8], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked]
```

It does not appear I'm getting the entire response, how do I manage to get the rest of the response? I'm just making the standard `restTemplate.exchange(api, method, request, clazz)` call.